# Content and Data call intensive Application in Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I started working on a Titanium application which is Content and data call intensive application.

I need some guidance regarding the best practices to be followed when building such application.
I am pretty much aware of the commonJS approach. I want to know best-practice coding to limit or eliminate memory/cacheing problems in Appcelerator. How do one approach or deal with these issues?

Thanks

Comment: what is the specific memory caching problem you are referencing here?

Comment: Hi Aaron, memory caching we can say as memory leaks or the data keeps on getting in the application when there is proper memory release. and how I manage to run my app in single context(is it mandatory to keep your running in single context?).

Answer (score 2):

I use a hybrid of MVC and M V VM I came up with:

MVC is appropiate for web URLs for redirectint yoursite/user and take the user as a param. Hence the Controller is the point of entry of the applicaiton.

In .net's MVVM pattern, the View is the Point of entry of the application. View requests ViewModel (connect events to UI) and ViewModel requests to Business (Model). Finally when data is reached, the data is "reflected" through event bubbling. This sounds cumbersome but it really ain't

Using that same approach I use the following

UI > C > B > Tech > Internet

And on Controller I suscribe Events, where in Tech I triggered them.

Where "Tech" abstracts all technical (SQLite, JSON, Ti.App.Properties, etc)

The Business knows Entities and Icons, but no technical aspect

```
getIcon('Badge'){ tech.getIcon('Badge') } )
```

Where in technical we could have a dictionary like var

```
getIcon(icon)
{
    var Icon = { 
            'Badge': 'src/cfg/img/badge.png' 
        }  

    return Icon[icon]
}
```

So the controller would look something like:

```
oTable = ui.TableEmployees() // our custom made TableView at 'ui.js'
Ti.App.addEventListener( 'EmployeesUpdated', function(e){ oTable.data = e.data } )
```

lastly, everytime I need to update info, I go

```
business.refreshEntity('Employees')
```

where business access Tech

```
tech = require('src/tech')
refreshEntity(entity){ tech.refreshEntity(entity) }
```

finally in tech

```
refreshEntity(entity)
{
    HTTPClient = new Ti.Network.HTTPClient( { onload:..., onerror:... } )
    HTTPClient.send()
    data = transform(response)
    if (data != cachedData)
        Ti.App.fireEvent( 'EmployeesUpdated', {data: data} )
}
```

That way you can have pull on refresh-es, timers, etc. and ONLY if the data changed then you promote it to all your affected views

Comment: I like your approach to this, as I am also a big fan of MVC/MVVM design. Just a point of curiosity... how do you handle your cachedData? Meaning, is that an array that is directly comparable to your data object? Do you use a custom comparer? Is that cached data just stored in memory (resource concern for large data sets), or in SQLite or similar? I think the caching issue is something important in this conversation, due to Ajeet Pratap Maurya's concern about performance, memory, and caching. Thanks :)

Comment: thanks JC Guerrero for your answer. I too use a similar procedure. I have my view.js file which uses controller.js for any event attached to its controls and which in further can call to the model.js which calls a WS or any sql db or any custom function. but with commonJS how to keep our whole application running under single context and how to achieve caching of the data.